# Finding a string within a text box and getting how far that is from the start of the textbox

Tags: c#

eh sorry for the long title but anyway back to the point I have been looking around for a while now I can't find anything to help me ok so my "problem" is that i got a string within my appand I need to goto a char and remove all text after it
example of what i wanted help with:

```
string S = "Somthing_SetSomthing   ExtraUnwantedTextHere";
```

and then I want to remove everything but the first set of chars up until the space bar

and here is a screen shot of a real world example of what I wanted help with
https://i.gyazo.com/e2bfe3d19b76cab8bc3f4d39d2c96b45.png

Thanks in advance C:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index of the first space using `IndexOf` (the position within the string this occurs). Then use `Substring` to get a value from the start of the string (`0`) up to that index:

```
string text = "Somthing_SetSomthing   ExtraUnwantedTextHere";

int index = text.IndexOf(' ');

string trimmed = text.Substring(0, index);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/grBGfx) for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the position where you want to cut the string. Then, if, the character is found, take the characters up to that location:

```
var index = S.IndexOf(' ');
if (index >= 0)
{
    var result = S.Substring(0, index);
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding a check for index>=0

Comment: Thanks TaW. Updated my answer to include this.

Comment: That is one way, but the ultimate decision what to do is up to the op: maybe the result should be undefined or  throw an error or simply be the full string..

Answer (score 1):

The position of first space in the string is:

```
string text = "Somthing_SetSomthing   ExtraUnwantedTextHere";
int SpaceCount1 = text.IndexOf(' ');
```

the position of the next space is:

```
int SpaceCount2 = text.IndexOf(' ', SpaceCount1 + 1);
```

Get the first part of the string up to the second space is:

```
string firstPart = text.Substring(0, SpaceCount2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are looking for a space (whitespace) I would use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) and get the first element from this:

```
    string sample = "Somthing_SetSomthing   ExtraUnwantedTextHere";

    string toLeft = sample.Split()[0];
    Console.WriteLine("{0}*", toLeft);    // Somthing_SetSomthing*
```

Comment: `string.Split` seems like overkill, you don't need to keep searching for further space-delimited components after you've found the first.

Comment: Unless performance became an issue I would still use it, personally.